# Build 2^n in double/simd

Tags: assembly, simd

I am trying to build 2^n using the double representation. The trick is (well) known

```
// tips to calculate 2^n using the exponent of the double IEEE representation
union ieee754{
    double d;
    uint32_t i[2];
};

// Converts an unsigned long long to a double
inline double uint642dp(uint64_t ll) {
  ieee754 tmp;
  tmp.ll=ll;
  return tmp.d;
}
-----------------------------------
// e^x = 2^n e^y, n = round(x/log(2)+0.5)

double x = 4.3; // start from there
double y = round(x/log(2)+0.5)
int n = (int)y; // convert in to double 
uint642dp(( ((uint64_t)n) +1023)<<52); // calculate 2^n fastly
```

if n = 4, it will return 16.

Presently I am looking for the same this but for SIMD calculation. Considering SSE2 double, after the round function I will get a register sse2 __m128d v = (4.0, 3.0); form this register how calculate 2^v ... I am blocked mainly due to the cast __m128d to __m128i, it does not exist (it still exists a cast but it does not move bit, just change the "interpretation" of the register double/int).

I do not want return the datas form simd register to normal register to make the transformation. It exists certainly a tips with SIMD, but I do not know it.

So Help ^_^'

Best,

Comment: This is probably a pointless optimisation, since int -> float/double conversion on SSE is already very fast and generating 2^n as an int is trivial of course.

Comment: The "trick" (the `union` abuse) unfortunately is not valid C++ ...

Comment: why don't use `(double)(1 << n)`?

Answer (score 2):

The *trick* you are looking for is actually the `_mm256_castsi256_pd` intrinsic which allows you to convert a SIMD-array of integers into a SIMD-array of doubles. This is only for C/C++ type checking and does not translate into any instruction.

Here is a snippet of code to perform this operation (only valid within some bounds of exponent):

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m256d pow2n (__m256i n)
{
    const __m256i bias = _mm256_set1_epi64x( 1023 );
    __m256i t = _mm256_add_epi64 (n, bias);
    t = _mm256_slli_epi64 (t, 52);
    return _mm256_castsi256_pd (t) ;
}

#include <cstdio>

int main ()
{
        __m256i rn = _mm256_set_epi64x( 7, 9, 4, 2 );
        __m256d pn = pow2n (rn) ;
        double v [4] ;
        _mm256_storeu_pd (v, pn) ;
        printf ("v = %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]) ;
        return 0 ;
}
```

`pow2n` compiles to only 2 insns, [as you can see on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QFt3gC4CdwB0AFgHwBQZA%2BpegEwCsAbHEgA4D2A7rWEgBTU6TEEjABKMgG8ySWUgjswAZ2xJBDRiIBGIAIZKkAXjWYNlJQmwBGSglYhGAFgAefJFYAMtAMxIxAbhk5dWEkVWMaIUZKXTg4W3snfjAAGiQdfTEkQLkwoxMo8ygoEASHR35sNPpaAKDZXEsYXF5Iswh9bCUQM1YWPmwswIBfClBIWERUCBU4EHZyMhwkdF1wfglpXNyQzSQW/Lamc0syp1ckAHY0gE40xzTaPxzt2V2WVl5jDm5ePhahvVtnB2DAtFBkAA3JAAbUcAF1skCdqZjip2I0YJQ%2BvxIWlPoDXrJWPgwNgAGb8ABE0OMAFIoJSGUzGUhmQAdMBUtKQmEeeE8mFWAVIXm0EW87zwwlExrYZq8DxI4ZAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

Output is :

```
v = 4.000000 16.000000 512.000000 128.000000
```

This requires AVX2, but a 128bit version would only require SSE2.  Note the exponents are provided as 64bit integers.  If you have 32bit integers, use `_mm256_cvtepu32_epi64`.

If you're starting with a vector of `double`, like the OP, then use `_mm256_cvtpd_epi32` and `_mm256_cvtepu32_epi64`.  (double -> int64 directly isn't available until AVX-512).

Comment: Nice answer.  In C++11, you can just use `alignas(32)` instead of non-standard `__declspec` (GNU C vs. MSVC differ on this).  Also, I might have used `_mm256_set_epi64x( 7, 9, 4, 2 )` for the initializer, instead of the `int64_t` array.  Also, in English, it's `bias`, not `biais` :)

Comment: @PeterCordes, Thanks. I did not know the alignas(32) from C++11, thanks for mentioning, feel free to edit the post accordingly. For the `_mm256_set_epi64x`, I was being lazy using it, remembering that some compiler headers don't expose it with exact same naming. As for English, you got me ! (just edited the post).

Comment: I had to check to see if it was `epi64x` or `epi64`.  Compilers/linkers do a good of merging vector constants, just like how they merge identical string literals into a single definition, so it's almost always best to use `_mm_set1` or `_mm_set` to assign constants to local variables, rather than putting them in static const storage yourself.  (Unfortunately `static const __m128 foo = _mm_set()` sucks:  that will run a constructor at startup instead of having the data in `foo` to start with).

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks a lot for your edit. My compiler version yields a broadcast though, care should be taken for the flags though.

Comment: Intel's intrinsics guide only lists [`_mm256_set1_epi64x`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_set1&expand=4618), so hopefully it's safe to use across all compilers.  It works for gcc and clang.  Loading a 32B constant with a `vpbroadcastq` is probably a good thing, since it's as cheap as a `vmovdqa` on Intel hardware.  Any decent compiler will hoist the broadcast-load out of a loop after inlining, so it doesn't have to load it every time through the loop, whether it's with a broadcast or not.